# How to tell which Launch Agent is running

Tags: mac, launchd, macos

I'm a script kiddie noob so sorry if I get some of the jargon wrong or if this is a dumb question but...

I have written a launch agent that runs an application I also wrote at specified times to launch iTunes and play music to act as an alarm. The problem is that I've turned it off over Christmas and this morning it still went off. The launch agent I turned off with

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/wake.up.plist
```

doesn't appear in the list when I use

```
sudo launchctl list
```

so I'm fairly sure that either it's loaded in some other place (is that even possible?) or it's loaded under some other name that I can't pick out of the list.

The system.log at the time the alarm launches has

> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.iTunes.1636[1646]): Service exited
>   due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by killall[1803]

But my gut tells me this isn't the thing I need to be unloading.

Has anyone got any suggestions for how I can work out what launch agent is running here?